# Database Design for Pharmacy store with wholesale and retial

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-5.7

I have designed a DB ( Inventory Management ) for Pharmacy Store  which will sell medicine both wholesale and retail. I store each units with its conversion for medicine in a separate fields for retail selling.

[image]

When I generate the inventory movement report or sum transactions, I need to calculate the each ordered units and it makes my logic very complex. Is there any better approach for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: that is actually not very complex and looks good

Comment: Based on my understanding of units, that looks good.  To make it easier to query and understand, create views for the units. where you will have a order product unit view, prices units view, and product units view.

Comment: Can you provide report queries ?